# Zooming to point of interest

Tags: opengl, mathematics

I have the following variables:

- Point of interest which is the position(x,y) in pixels of the place
  to focus.
- Screen width,height which are the dimensions of the window.
- Zoom level which sets the zoom level of the camera.

And this is the code I have so far.

```
void Zoom(int pointOfInterestX,int pointOfInterstY,int screenWidth,
   int screenHeight,int zoomLevel)
{   
glScalef(1,1,1);
glTranslatef( (pointOfInterestX/2) - (screenWidth/2), (pointOfInterestY/2) - (screenHeight/2),0);

glScalef(zoomLevel,zoomLevel,1);
}
```

And I want to  do zoom in/out but keep the point of interest in the middle of the screen. but so far all of my attempts have failed and I would like to ask for some help.

Comment: Do you have zooming and centering working separately otherwise? Seems like you're asking people to write your code for you.

Comment: Yes i have tried look at the edited post.Centering works but not when zooming in..

Comment: Do you zoom back to "normal" before translating?

Comment: Yes.I have even tried to multiply each result axis by zoom level but nothing ;(

Comment: What are you using for a camera? That's likely where you'd want to do the zoom.

Comment: I do not have a camera yet since i don't need one , i only set the point of interest to mouse position.My guess is that im not calculating the middle point correctly when zooming...

Comment: Well, when i was doing something like this, i got better results making my viewport smaller and stretching it on screen than using `glScalef`, since `glScalef` will mess your coordinates. `glOrthof` may help you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want zoom just like in google maps? If you hover over city and zoom there cursor stays top of that city. This give smooth transition.

```
        public static final void zoom(float amount, float toX, float toY) {
            float oldZ = camera.zoom;
            camera.zoom += amount;
            // If zooming still has effect then we need translate map towards cursor
            if (camera.zoom < minZoom) {
                    camera.zoom = minZoom;
            } else if (camera.zoom > maxZoom) {
                    camera.zoom = maxZoom;
            } else {
                    float a = (toX - (float) HALFSCREENSIZEX)
                                    * (oldZ - camera.zoom);
                    float b = (-toY + (float) HALFSCREENSIZEY)
                                    * (oldZ - camera.zoom);
                    camera.translate(a, b, 0);
             //check boundaries if you have any.
            }
    }
```

To make this work with matrix stack you might have to peek there http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.java

Zooming is just multiplier for viewport size there. I have done this with matrix stack too but its much cleaner to use camera class.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i've solved the problem like a month ago :D

Comment: @user1010005 how?